# vlookup for most common row

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

I am trying to populate ColumnA in Table1 with the most common value of ColumnB in Table2, where ColumnC in Table2 matches ColumnC in Table1.

Something like:

Table1.ColumnA = Max(if(Table1.ColumnC = Table2.ColumnC, Table2.ColumnB))

I have tried a vlookup with no success. I have also created a pivot table to show the aggregated values but don't know how to query it from TableA.ColumnA

Thank you in advance,
Kevin.

Comment: Are the tables pivot tables? or just structured tables?

Comment: Or are they just flat data?

Comment: The tables have just been pasted into separate worksheets then formatted as tables. I created a pivot table on Table2 firstly to validate the data and then to query but I could not figure out how and would like to be able to change the data in Table2 later on without needing to refresh the pivot. But if it's easier to query the pivot then that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(Table2[B],MODE(IF(Table2[C]=[@C],MATCH(Table2[B],Table2[B],0))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Using an intermediary pivot table.

Create the pivot table with the name column as the rows and the one to count as the columns and data.

Then you can use this long formula:

```
=INDEX($B$16:$D$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(INDEX($B$17:$D$19,MATCH([@C],$A$17:$A$19,0),0))-MIN(COLUMN(INDEX($B$17:$D$19,MATCH([@C],$A$17:$A$19,0),0)))+1)/(MAX(INDEX($B$17:$D$19,MATCH([@C],$A$17:$A$19,0),0))=INDEX($B$17:$D$19,MATCH([@C],$A$17:$A$19,0),0)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting a data type error. All the columns are set to general so I set them to text and still get the same error.

Comment: The value in the formula is of the wrong data type. Here is the formula I have entered based on your example: =INDEX(Table3[[#Headers],[Asset Class Trim]],MODE(IF(Table3[[#Headers],[MATKL]]=[@MATKL],MATCH(Table3[[#Headers],[Asset Class Trim]],Table3[[#Headers],[Asset Class Trim]],0)))). The result is #VALUE! with the data type error

Comment: Why are you including the headers?

Comment: Also make sure you are using Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter.

Comment: That's how I selected the column, by clicking on the header. I am guessing I should not do that?

Comment: No, `Table3[[#Headers],[Asset Class Trim]]` should be `Table3[Asset Class Trim]` change all to remove the headers.

Comment: Ah! ok, I have fixed the formula and pressed Ctrl-Shift-Enter. There is no error and it says it's calculating: (4 Processor(s)): 0% at the moment. It a large spreadsheet (Table 3 is just over 700,000 rows! so I am guessing this might take a while.

Comment: Ummmmmm.....Yeah, it is an array formula and for every row in you first table it is doing over 1.4 million calculations.   leave the question open, someone may have a non array version.

Comment: Trying to figure out if there is anything I can do with the pivot table